# HTML page not displayed correctly on different browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, iceweasel

I have the following html page which takes urls from a file and display them. The images are resized to fit the screen to avoid the need to scroll. My problem is it is displayed correctly on firefox but iceweasel just display an empty page. This got me really confused because I did not find anything on it. Thank you for your help.

The images all have a Width 400 and Height 400 but iceweasal states the first image has Width 0 and Heigth 19. If I load the page and refresh it a few times the page is displayed correctly.

The html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><style>
.col-md-3 img {
    float:left;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
}
</style>
<script>    
var inRowLimit = 3;

function resizeImgs() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    var count = images.length;
    var rows = 1;
    if (count > inRowLimit) {
        rows = Math.ceil(count/3);
        count = inRowLimit;
    }
    var maxWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/count);
    var maxHeight = window.innerHeight/rows;
    for(var i=0; i<=images.length; i++) {
        var currW = document.getElementById('img'+i).offsetWidth;
        var stretchW = maxWidth/currW;
        var currH  = document.getElementById('img'+i).offsetHeight;
        var stretchH = maxHeight/currH;
        if (stretchW <= stretchH)     
            document.getElementById('img'+i).style.width=currW*stretchW+'px';
         } else {
            document.getElementById('img'+i).style.height=currH*stretchH+'px';
        }           
      }
   }

function go() {
    <!--abstracted-->
    loadImgs(file);
}

function loadImgs(infile) {
    <!--abstracted-->
    resizeImgs();
}
window.onload = go
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="images">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you made sure all images have been completely loaded already …?

Comment: How can I make sure they are?

Answer (score 0):

Why wont you use some css to resize the images? You can make use of css for images:
    .col-md-3 img {
       display: block;
       float:left;
       width: 33.3333%;
       max-width: 100%;
       height: auto;
    }
As far as I unterstand your problem js code for resize is completely unnecessary.

Seems its issue with running code when browsers hasn't copmletely downloaded images.
You should execute your code after window load evenet was fired.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load

Comment: To build on to this answer, you (@user2196234) got the images in place after a few tries because the browser had cached them, so they had loaded in time for the script to take on.

Comment: I have updated my question and added window.onload but it still does not work

Comment: If all images are 400x400 I think you could try to add width and height attributes to your img tags.

Comment: The current set of images are all 400x400 but this might not be the case in the future.

Comment: If I use your css snippet nothing happends at all.